# How to insert text into database based on separation keys

Tags: php, mysql, import

If i've the following database table `my_table` (id,year,event)

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `year` text,
  `event` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now i would like to import some data inside this database `my_table` from text file with the following exact text example.

```
2011|Italy hosts the 68th Venice International Film Festival<br>
2011|Severe damage occurs as wildfires sweep through Oklahoma<br>
2010|In Sudan Liberation Army will demobilize child soldiers<br>
```

Can be done manually but for millions of events, it is impossible so i've been thinking to use another solution where it can depends on `|` To separate the year from the event then insert it into database where it stopped at `<br>` to roll another insertion after.

Any idea how can it be done, this would save months if done manually and also will teach important idea using php solutions  ~Thanks

results i think should be

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(3) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `year` text,
  `event` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (1, '2011', 'Italy hosts the 68th Venice International Film Festival');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (2, '2011', 'Severe damage occurs as wildfires sweep through Oklahoma');
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES (3, '2010', 'In Sudan Liberation Army will demobilize child soldiers');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html). It allows you to specify separators (`|`) and line terminators (`<br>\n`).